# Wordpress wp_enqueue_script my function is not executed

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've tried a lot of syntaxes thanks to many subjects I found here about how to make wp_enqueue_script works for external JS scripts...

My goal is to affect a class to post elements coming from ecwd event Plugin, because after having made register_taxonomy_for_object_type work and showing post coming from the plug as regular post when affected to regular category, one problem remains: the posts coming from the plug are not displayed with the regular post style when displayed one the categorie page.
I've figured out that the class "post" was missing in this case.
So I'm trying to add this class

But my script seems not being launched.
I verified that I'm pointing to the right path for the script file by Printing the script file source path. 
I put console.debug at the beginning of the function to see if the script has been launched but nothing is written in the console...

Here is the code :

In the Theme function.php :

```
function MAJ_Post_Class() {
    if( is_category() ) {
        $scriptSrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/MAJ_ecwd_event_Post.js';
        print $scriptSrc;
        wp_register_script('Change_EcwdClass', $scriptSrc, array('jquery'),'1.4.1', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('Change_EcwdClass');
        print "Passe wp_enqueue_script" ;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'MAJ_Post_Class' );
```

In the MAJ_ecwd_event_Post.js file :

```
(function ($) {
    function Change_EcwdClass() {
        console.debug("Try To Write");
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ecwd_event");
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
        {
          var el = elements[i];
          el.setAttribute( "class", el.getAttribute("class") + " post" );
          console.debug(el.getAttribute("class"));
        }
    }
});
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: and where you called `Change_EcwdClass` to see `Try To Write` in the console. also, why not to just look at loaded scripts to see, if your `enqueued` is there( or not )?

Comment: Well if you mean to check if the js file is well listed in the navigator debug network source, yes it is.
And if I put a syntax error in the js file, I get an "uncaught syntax error" in the debugger too.
So my js file seems to be loaded but the script seems to be ignored...

Comment: In your `MAJ_ecwd_event_Post.js` file, it appears you never call `Change_EcwdClass()` so none of that code gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to cabrerahector, the call of the function was just missing, but not only. The (jQuery) statement was missing too.

So in fact the function worked almost well.

Here is the javascript version working :

```
(function ($) {
    function Change_EcwdClass() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ecwd_event");
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
        {
          var el = elements[i];
          el.setAttribute( "class", el.getAttribute("class") + " post" );
        }
    }
    Change_EcwdClass();
})(jQuery);
```

And here is the jQuery version:

```
(function ($) {
    $('.ecwd_event').addClass('post');
})(jQuery);
```